# Uncaught promise DOM exception in service-worker.js

Tags: service-worker, next.js, sw-precache

Service worker registered successfully but I'm still getting the above error in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

What verb/action caused the error? You know you can't access the DOM in an SW right?